# How do you fix: NameError: name 'poll' is not defined in Django?

Tags: python, django

I am doing the Django tutorial, where I created a model, did syncdb, and started the python shell. However, when I run the code poll.objects.all(), it shows an error:

```
>>> poll.objects.all()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'poll' is not defined
```

No matter what I try the same error keeps coming:
    NameError: name 'poll' is not defined

I am trying to figure out how to resolve this so I can use the various db lookup functions. I have already imported the classes:

> > > from polls.models import Poll, Choice

How do you fix this?

Comment: this is from the django tutorial, so it's not "unlikely to help any future visitors," or an "extraordinarily narrow situation."  I'm having exactly the same problem: please reopen the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo. Try `Poll` instead of `poll`

```
  Poll.objects.all()
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to import the model
like 
from your_app.models import Poll
Poll.objects.all()

Answer (score 0):

You're importing `Poll` then using `poll`. Python is case sensitive.